# How to shift the colorbar position to right

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I draw a scatter chart as below :
[image]

The code is :

```
sc = plt.scatter(x, y, marker='o', s=size_r, c=clr, vmin=lb, vmax=ub, cmap=mycm, alpha=0.65)
cbar = plt.colorbar(sc, shrink=0.9)
```

And I want to shift the colorbar to right a little bit to extend the drawing area. How to do that ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `pad` attribute.

```
cbar = plt.colorbar(sc, shrink=0.9, pad = 0.05)
```

The documentation of [make_axes()](http://matplotlib.org/api/colorbar_api.html#matplotlib.colorbar.make_axes) describes how to use `pad`: "pad: 0.05 if vertical, 0.15 if horizontal; fraction of original axes between colorbar and new image axes".

Comment: How could you move a horizontal color bar left or right?

Answer (score 13):

Actually you can put the colorbar anywhere you want.

```
fig1=figure()
sc = plt.scatter(x, y, marker='o', s=size_r, c=clr, vmin=lb, vmax=ub, cmap=mycm, alpha=0.65)
position=fig1.add_axes([0.93,0.1,0.02,0.35])  ## the parameters are the specified position you set 

fig1.colorbar(sc,cax=position) ##
```