# Reduce space between subplots and colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to know how to reduce the space between subplots and the colorbar. By the way, I have included `fig.tight_layout()`; that does not reduce the space between figures nor the colobar.

This is my code below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

diff_array_num_BayesHier = pd.read_csv("diff_array_num_BayesHier.csv")
diff_array_num_MLE = pd.read_csv("diff_array_num_MLE.csv")

diff_array_num_BayesHier = diff_array_num_BayesHier.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1)
diff_array_num_MLE = diff_array_num_MLE.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1)

sdo = pd.read_csv('~/Desktop/sdo.csv')
colnames = [1,3,6,12,24,48]

diff_array_num_BayesHier.index = sdo['SDO_Name']
diff_array_num_MLE.index = sdo['SDO_Name']

diff_array_num_BayesHier.columns = colnames
diff_array_num_MLE.columns = colnames

vmin = min(diff_array_num_BayesHier.min().min(), diff_array_num_MLE.min().min())
vmax = max(diff_array_num_BayesHier.max().max(), diff_array_num_MLE.max().max())


fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,5))

im1 = ax1.imshow(diff_array_num_BayesHier,cmap='Reds', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(len(colnames)))
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(len(sdo['SDO_Name'])))
ax1.set_xticklabels(colnames)
ax1.set_yticklabels(sdo['SDO_Name'])
# ax1.xticks(np.arange(len(colnames)), colnames)
# ax1.yticks(np.arange(len(sdo['SDO_Name'])), sdo['SDO_Name'])

im2 = ax2.imshow(diff_array_num_MLE,cmap='Reds', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
ax2.set_xticks(np.arange(len(colnames)))
ax2.set_yticks([])  # Remove y-axis tick labels
ax2.set_xticklabels(colnames)
# ax2.xticks(np.arange(len(colnames)), colnames)
# ax2.yticks(np.arange(len(sdo['SDO_Name'])), sdo['SDO_Name'])


cax = fig.add_axes([0.92, 0.15, 0.02, 0.7])  # [left, bottom, width, height]
cbar = plt.colorbar(im1, cax=cax)
cbar.set_label('Colorbar Label')

im2.set_clim(vmin, vmax)

#plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=-1)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('output_plot.png', dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Adding `plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=-1)` reduces the space between the two figures, but not the colobar.

[image]

How can I reduce the space between the all features figures and colobar?

Comment: Have you tried using `pad`? Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330332/how-to-shift-the-colorbar-position-to-right-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Also, reduce the `figsize(...)`

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the `left` value in `fig.add_axes([0.92, 0.15, 0.02, 0.7])`? (replacing 0.92 with 0.8 for instance)

Answer (score 0):

In the code below I've added the colour bar based on `im2`, which I think should be okay as `im2` has the same `vmin/vmax` range as `im1`.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Synthetic data
data = np.random.randn(20, 6)
df = pd.DataFrame(data,
                  index=['row_' + chr(ord('A') + i) for i in range(20)],
                  columns=[1, 3, 6, 12, 24, 48])
df2 = df ** 2

#Plot
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))

vmin, vmax = -1, 1
colnames = df.columns
rownames = df.index

im1 = ax1.imshow(df, cmap='Reds', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(len(colnames)))
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(len(rownames)))
ax1.set_xticklabels(colnames)
ax1.set_yticklabels(rownames)

im2 = ax2.imshow(df2, cmap='Reds', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
ax2.set_xticks(np.arange(len(colnames)))
ax2.set_yticks([])
ax2.set_xticklabels(colnames)

#Add colour bar based on im2
# This should be ok as im2 has the same range as im1.
cbar = fig.colorbar(im2)
cbar.set_label('Colorbar Label')

im2.set_clim(vmin, vmax)

fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=-1)
```